# recursive function going into infinite loop despite condition check

Tags: python, recursion

I have a list

```
s = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

I try to reverse in place using a recursive function

```
def reverse_string4(arr, start=0):
    while start < len(arr):
        arr.insert(start, arr.pop())
        reverse_string4(arr, start + 1)
```

the above goes into an infinite loop, but this one below works

```
def reverse_string2(arr, start=0):
    if start == len(arr)-1:
        pass
    else:
        arr.insert(start, arr.pop())
        reverse_string2(arr, start + 1)
```

I am confused when debug start variable increases, then why is not terminating while loop?

Comment: The `while` is an infinite loop. There's nothing in the body of the loop that would make the while condition false. Why do you think you need a while loop *and* recursion?

Comment: then when start becomes 5 why is not terminating the while loop?

Comment: Use `if` instead of `while` loop because there is no need of `while` looping in recursion. `if start < len(arr):` will also work.

Comment: `start` does not become 5. When you recursively call `reverse_string2` you create a new run of the function with its own variables and its own `start`. But in the original run, the `start` variable that the while-loop is looking at still has the same value, so it still loops.

Comment: tldr: a recursive call is not a goto.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily see what's happening by adding `print()` statements.

```py
def reverse_string4(arr, start=0):
    print('-> arr %s, start=%i' % (arr, start))
    while start < len(arr):
        print('start %i < len(arr) %i' % (start, len(arr)))
        arr.insert(start, arr.pop())
        print('call reverse_string()')
        reverse_string4(arr, start + 1)
        print('back from call')
```

Run it with `reverse_string4(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])`:

```
-> arr ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], start=0
start 0 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l'], start=1
start 1 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'h', 'e', 'l'], start=2
start 2 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'h', 'e'], start=3
start 3 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=4
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=5
back from call
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=5
back from call
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=5
back from call
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=5
back from call
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
-> arr ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'], start=5
back from call
start 4 < len(arr) 5
call reverse_string()
```

See? The `while` condition is still true, so it stays in the `while` loop.

The proper fix is to use *either* a `while` loop or recursion (and then, probably `return` the value called by the recursive call).

Comment: Thanks, I notice in debug window that once the start becomes 5, it goes back to 4 and that goes infinite.
Then do you mean that while and recursive call should not be used together? This is how I understand it.

Comment: That's basically the gist of this, yes. It's not impossible to combine the two but if you are only just learning, probably don't even try. The standard logic is simply `if (something): return recursive_call(): else: return base case` and the recursion is what takes care of any (implicit) looping.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am learning and practise various exersises.